# How can I remove numbers, and words with length below 2, from a sentence?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove words that have length below 2 and any word that is numbers. For example

```
 s = " This is a test 1212 test2"
```

Output desired is

```
" This is test test2"
```

I tried `\w{2,}` this removes all the word whose length is below 2. When I added `\D+` this removes all numbers when I didn't want to get rid of 2 from `test2`.

Comment: @P....This doesn't remove 1212. This should be removed since it is a number. I was able to remove all words with 2 words or less by \w{2,}

Comment: What is a "word" ?

Comment: @Maxt8r, words are alpha character or alphacharacter that might have number character joined. For instance test. test1, tes2 are words whereas 1 , 2,  0.2 0.4 are not word

Comment: Are the 2 letter requirement cocsequtive or within the "word" ?

Comment: @Maxt8r only within "word"

Comment: Maybe `(?:\b\d+\b|\b[a-z]\b)[ \t]*` https://regex101.com/r/NyDnyV/1

Comment: Do you want to replace consecutive whitespaces by one too (regarding your desired output) ?

Comment: Non-regex solution: `" ".join([x for x in s.split() if not x.isdigit() and not (x == x[0] and x.isalpha())])` ([demo](https://ideone.com/TAytyG)). Only trailing/leading whitespaces get removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```
s = re.sub(r'\b(?:\d+|\w)\b\s*', '', s)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ph0m8O/3)

**Pattern Details:**

- `\b`: Match word boundary
- `(?:\d+|\w)`: Match a single word character or 1+ digits
- `\b`: Match word boundary
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces

Comment: Changing the order to `\d+|\w` prevents unnecessary backtracking.

Comment: Very good point @ctwheels I definitely missed out this one

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of work boundaries `'\b'` and remove anything that is 1 character long inside boundaries: number or letter, doesn't matter.
Also remove anything between boundaries that is just numbers:

```
import re

s = " This is a test 1212 test2"

print( re.sub(r"\b([^ ]|\d+)\b","",s))
```

Output:

```
 This is  test  test2
```

Explanation:

```
\b(           word boundary followed by a group
   [^ ]           anything that is not a space (1 character) 
       |              or
        \d+       any amount of numbers
)             followed by another boundary
```

is replaced by `re.sub(pattern, replaceBy, source)` with `""`.

Comment: Change the order to `\d+|[^ ]` prevents unnecessary backtracking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `(?i)\b(?:\d+|[a-z])\b[ \t]*`
https://regex101.com/r/bnS15k/1

Does some wsp trimming.

---

Whitespace trimming is probably more important for these kind of things.
This modded version does it from both sides.

Just subs it using
`(?im)(?:([ \t])+\b(?:\d+|[a-z])\b[ \t]*[ \t]*|^\b(?:\d+|[a-z])\b[ \t]*[ \t]*())`
With replace  `\1\2`

https://regex101.com/r/gSswPe/1
Strips wsp from both sides.

```
 (?im)
 (?:
    ( [ \t] )+           # (1)
    \b 
    (?: \d+ | [a-z] )
    \b [ \t]* [ \t]* 
  | 
    ^ \b 
    (?: \d+ | [a-z] )
    \b [ \t]* [ \t]* 
    ( )                  # (2)
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
import re

s = " This is a test 1212 test2"

p = re.compile(r"(\b(\w{0,1})\b)|(\b(\d+)\b)")

result = p.sub('', s)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
" This is  test  test2"
```

I noticed that your desired output does not contain consecutive whitespaces.
If you want to replace consecutive whitespaces by one, you can do this:

```
p = re.compile(r"  +")
result = p.sub(' ', result)
```

Output:

```
" This is test test2"
```

`(\b(\w{0,1})\b)` this group matches words with length up to 1 (included)

`(\b(\d+)\b)` this group matches word composed of digit(s) only

`|` The pipe means "or", so this expression will match either group 1 or group 2

`\b` It's the "word boundary". By surrounding some regex with "\b", it will match "whole words only"

`\w` It will match wharacters supposed to part of a word

`\d+` This means "at least one digit or more"

Note that what `\b` and  `\w` will match will depends on the regex flavor you are using.

Comment: `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?` - shorter and more concise. Also, changing the order prevents unnecessary backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my two cents in - you could use the inbuilt string functions:

```
s = " This is a test 1212 test2"
result = " ".join(word for word in s.split() 
                  if len(word) >= 2 and not word.isdigit())
print(result)
```

Which would yield

```
This is test test2
```